# "Offensive" Low Quality Post Audit Failed -- Possible Bug

Tags: bug, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing Low Quality posts, I came across one: 
https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6762689

Additionally, here is the revision history for the answer, which is important in this case:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27667823/revisions

The last time the answer was edited was back in December and I was presented with the answer being:

```
Use `[Height(cm)]` instead of `Height(cm)`.
```

The answer is indeed short and perhaps could be expanded on, but not of extreme low-quality. At least, not low enough quality for me to recommend deletion. Therefore, I selected "Looks OK."

Turns out I failed an audit... It claims the answer "has severe quality issues" and it is "abusive, nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable." None of which are true.

[image]

However, when you go back and look at the revision history of the post, the original post had a questionable link in it that had since been removed two edits ago. Since that information isn't presented from the basic review interface, and the answer I was shown in the review process did not look spammy, I feel that this is a bug in the audit process.

It seems as if the auditing system for the review process is looking at all (and non-current) edits, instead of whatever the most recent one is.

Comment: The same sort of thing happened to me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6843202).  I found the Stop! message more offensive than the post I reviewed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is just an unfortunate series of events. Here's a timeline of events on that answer, with only the relevant events presented:

```
13:43  Answer Posted
13:44  Answer Flagged (Spam)
13:44  Answer Edited (removed spam link)
13:48  Answer Edited (Improved formatting)
13:52  Flags Handled (Helpful)

00:12  Post Deleted
```

So both of the edits occurred before the spam flag ever got handled, which means the "don't select review audits that have been edited" rule didn't get applied, because their were no edits after the flag was handled. Technically, the spam flag should have been cleared as disputed since the spam link was no longer present in the post.

Normally, this wouldn't have caused any problems, because the post was not deleted. However, three users eventually came along and opted that the answer should be deleted (I will note, the answer went through Low Quality review, but the result was Looks OK x2 -- *none* of these deletion votes came from the Low Quality review). When the post was deleted, it then matched the review audit selection criteria:

- Deleted
- Has a Helpful spam flag
- No new edits since flag handled

I've gone ahead and cleared the spam flag off the answer, which subsequently undeleted it. I have no compelling reason to delete the answer again, so I'll leave that up to the community if they think it should be gone.

Comment: Yet more evidence that that automatic selection of audit questions is **fundamentally broken in concept**.  These need to be a hand-curated assortment of clear-cut cases.