# Offensive answers don't seem to get censored when manually deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, offensive, offensive-flag

#### Update

This originally was a feature request, but [Brad pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308428/456814) that suggestion #2 is how the system is supposed to work, so this actually appears to be a bug. Is it really a bug?

For what it's worth, I also might have found another distantly related bug around how [spam answers aren't censored properly if they've been manually edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308466/456814).

---

I've noticed that when an answer is flagged as offensive, and is *manually deleted* by 20k+ rep users *before* it acquires the [necessary 6 offensive flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/163250) to be auto-deleted by the system, the answer doesn't get the standard spam/offensive notice that such posts normally receive.

[Case in point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33235996/456814):

[image]

In the past I've manually censored such answers with the standard notice, but having to do so manually is frankly tiresome, and just seems to be less than ideal.

With that in mind, I have some suggestions about how we could possibly handle these cases better.

#### Suggestion #1: Allow Users to Flag Deleted Answers as Offensive

Currently the only flags that users can use on deleted answers are moderator-attention flags. We cannot flag a deleted answer with an *offensive* flag. I propose that users be allowed to flag deleted answers as offensive even when they are deleted, so that they can still be censored with an offensive notice automatically by the system.

Additionally, the OP of the answer should incur a -100 rep penalty (for main site answers), the same that would be incurred if the answer had accumulated 6 offensive flags before being manually deleted.

#### Suggestion #2: Auto-Censor Manually Deleted Answers that Have Accumulated Offensive Flags

As another possible improvement, when an answer is manually deleted by users, and the number of offensive flags on it is in the range `0 < flags < 6`, then the answer is again auto-censored by the system, as if it had acquired 6 offensive flags.

However, the answer owner *does not incur* a -100 rep penalty...at least not yet. When the answer is auto-censored, a moderator flag is automatically raised, so that a moderator can later verify that the answer should indeed receive an offensive notice. Upon verification, the moderator can then apply the -100 rep penalty, if appropriate.

#### Suggestion #3: Add an Edit Button That Will Auto-Apply an Offensive Notice

Finally, another possible improvement is just to add another edit button somewhere in the UI for 20+ users that will auto-apply an offensive notice to deleted answers. If users are going to censor such answers manually anyways, why not save them some copy & paste time?

Disadvantages: adding more buttons makes the UI more cluttered.

#### What do you guys think?

So do people think that any one of these suggestions are worth implementing? Or is it a waste of dev time, and users should just manually censor such answers when they're encountered?

Or, instead of modifying the system, should users instead change the way they handle offensive answers? Like, instead of manually deleting an offensive answer, should 20k+ users just stick to using offensive flags? I can see the advantage of being able to manually delete such answers, since it only requires 3 delete votes (vs 6 offensive flags) to remove the answers from public view.

Comment: Can't really comment in general since I don't have 10k rep, but surely this doesn't happen too often.  I think I've flagged like 2 posts/comments as offensive on the main site in the last year.  Anyway, in this specific case, Martijn already deleted the post and will likely take care of business.  So I guess that means I support the "use the existing offensive flag" option.

Comment: Is this really that big a problem? (Not saying it's not. I'm genuinely curious; it's just that in my experience, the few cases of this that I've seen seem to have been  handled quick enough.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I guess you're right, it's not really a big problem. I just find it to be annoying (personal problem). Though I do frequent a chat room [with a narc bot](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) that tends to dig this stuff up more frequently than what your typical SO user would encounter during an average week.

Comment: If you've been on Stack Overflow long enough to develop 10K reputation,  but deleted posts can still offend your delicate sensibilities ...

Comment: Note that #2 is also how audits are *successfully* picked at times. It's clear that that's the intention and that there's only a bug in certain aspects of that handling.

Comment: For what it's worth that deleted answer is hilarious.

Comment: I lol'd a bit seeing the image, but I keep asking how someone could have the courage to straight go down the line. I can understand rants a bit, because no one is perfect, but being straight offensive? SO could easily be linked to a professional with some research...

I don't get it then how someone would do that, in sane conditions. They also know we are goint to delete these fairly quickly.

Comment: Things originally worked as you describe, but the potential for abuse means that a spam/offensive flag needs to be handled as helpful before the censorship kicks in.

Comment: @Oded not sure I'm following - for instance [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816625/jsoup-iterate-over-elements-causes-duplicated-output/33198604#33198604)  - should that not be censored?

Comment: @JonClements - it should (2 spam flags marked as helpful). Though employees and moderators never see the censorship notice.

Comment: @Oded *ahhhh*... that'd explain that one then - thanks.

Comment: @Oded: Handled as helpful by whom? The system only?

Comment: @BoltClock - in general. Resolved as helpful either by moderators or automatically.

Comment: @Oded: What this bug report is saying is that the posts aren't being censored when the flags are handled by moderators.

Comment: @BoltClock - not sure what is going on there. There are rollbacks involved :/

Comment: @Oded: Cupcake had to manually apply the notice as an edit because it wasn't being automatically displayed. Not sure about the rest...

Answer (score 44):

Suggestion #2 should be [how the system has worked for years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199967/135615):

> Going forward, deleted answers that have had any spam or offensive
>   flags raised against them, will not show the answer body but the
>   following text:
>
> > This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details Where "the
> >     revision history" links to the answer revision history.
>
> The vote box (with score) and comments will still appear.
>
> With you in the next build (rev 2013.10.8.1061).

I've seen this work for manually deleted posts that had a single validated spam flag against them (not the six required for community deletion), such as in [this example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283744/offensive-low-quality-post-audit-failed-possible-bug). That's how things are supposed to function, hiding content that had any validated spam or offensive flags on them, no matter how they were deleted.

I had noticed that this did not apply to a recent offensive Meta post, so I thought that this was just an odd edge case that impacted Meta. As you point out, this seems to be happening on Stack Overflow too, so the behavior of this has changed at some point. This sounds to me like a regression, so I'd classify this as a bug report.

Comment: This naturally raises a couple of related issues: Are posts with 1 < flags < 6 still in easy reach when a ♦ is deciding whether someone needs a block, time out or just a stern warning? Would having 6 offensive flags help to identify potential problems as they develop? Is it worth skipping the delete vote to allow the problematic content to be deleted from the flags?

Comment: @theB - Almost all posts that are deleted with 1-5 spam or offensive flags on them are done so by moderators. There are rare cases where the user deletes the post, or where something is deleted in Low Quality Posts review, but those aren't particularly frequent. If a moderator is handling the flag, we know about any issues with the user and deal with them then. It's actually more of a problem when the community gets 6 spam or offensive flags on something before we see them, because we don't get notified about that. I do have a query I run to find posts destroyed in this manner, though.

Comment: Thanks for the information, its easier to know how to vote on [meta-tag:feature-request]s knowing the perspective from the other side of the wall. It does make the suggestion I made below kind of moot if mods are usually Larsoning the posts already. _(That combined with the re-classification of the question makes me wonder if the answer is worth deleting entirely.)_ The point you make about the flag deleted answers does make it seem like some kind of convenient hotlist for the ♦s might be helpful for rooting out problems.

Comment: actually the point is in the word "validated". When a mod validates an offensive flag, that triggers the same behaviour as 6 offensive flags from community. Or rather it's probably the other way round. I dare say that what you describe as intended behaviour was never the actual behaviour.

Comment: @Vogel612 - "validated" means "marked as helpful". This occurs either when a post with a spam / offensive flag on it is deleted (by a moderator or community votes) or when sufficient spam / offensive flags accrue to destroy the post. The only cases when a flag like this is not validated are when a moderator declines the flags or clears (disputes) them. A moderator's spam or offensive flag counts as 6 community flags, but isn't otherwise special. What I describe above *was* the actual behavior, as shown in the linked example. I also witnessed this on multiple occasions myself.