# Spam answer wasn't censored after a user edit, even after being deleted by Community

Tags: bug, edits, flags, spam

I noticed that [this spam answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33253050/456814) wasn't censored by the standard spam/offensive answer notice:

[image]

The revision history makes it clear that the spam answer was manually censored before it was deleted automatically by the system (presumably through the accumulation of 6 spam flags):

[image]

As I understand it, [the system is supposed to automatically censor posts with a spam/offensive answer notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199967/163250) when they're auto-deleted by the system, after the accumulation of 6 spam/offensive post flags:

> Going forward, deleted answers that have had any spam or offensive flags raised against them, will not show the answer body but the following text:
>
> > This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details

It appears that, at least in this case, having a user edit the spam somehow caused the notice to not be applied as it should have been. Am I right about this? Is this a bug? Or is there some other reasonable explanation that I'm not seeing?

#### Related bug(?) reports

[Earlier I noticed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308419/456814) that answers that are flagged as offensive but are deleted manually (instead of auto-deleted by the system) don't seem to get a spam/offensive notice either. I'm not sure if the two issues are related.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning your [previous post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308419/offensive-answers-dont-seem-to-get-censored-when-manually-deleted/308428#308428) for additional background?

Comment: @JonClements I didn't mention the other bug(?) report at first since the only apparent common element between them is that spam/offensive answers aren't getting a notice added when they should, but the scenarios in either case aren't exactly the same. But I'll go ahead and add a link.

Comment: @JonClements I noticed that [this spam answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33253747/456814) that you recently deleted didn't get a notice either. I'm starting to see a pattern where moderator deleted spam/offensive answers aren't receiving notices...

Comment: I can't see any post I've deleted with existing spam/offensive flags or "hard" flagged receive a notice.

Comment: So you admit you broke the system @JonClements? Users get suspend for less...

Comment: Wasn't there logic that resets flags if a post get edited? Is this maybe related with that?

Comment: @rene sounds like you might be on to something, though I'll need to dig through MSO or MSE to confirm. Is it is the case, however, then perhaps users should get a UI warning while attempting to edit posts that have pending spam and/or offensive flags on them, or perhaps even disallow editing altogether while such flags are pending.

Comment: @rene [the last paragraph here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/163250) explains the flag reset logic: "*Rolling back a post to a previous state will revert to the number of flags from that particular revision. This allows the OP (or someone else with edit rights) to rollback a post to which someone else introduced spam or offensive content in a later revision. However, as a general user, once you mark a post as spam or offensive, you cannot take it back.*"

Comment: Disallowing edits while flags are pending seems like a bad idea now, because if an otherwise valid post can be made 100% valid by removing offensive content, why not allow an edit?