# Offensive answers are not censored in "new answers to old questions" moderator tool

Tags: bug, spam, offensive, 10k-tools

In the [New Answers to Old Questions moderator tool](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) (accessible starting with 10k of reputation), it seems answers that were automatically deleted because 6 spam / offensive flags were raised are **not** censored / hidden.

The content of the answer is correctly censored when accessing the post directly (the answer appears as deleted by Community); the behaviour described here only concerns this specific moderator tool.

Picture of the moderator tool page, where the offensive text was hidden:

[image: Content of offensive answer is not hidden]

Is this a caching problem of some sort? Considering this only affects 10K+ users who happen to browse this tool in the 5 hour period the offensive content was posted, it seems pretty low priority, but still, I feel the content should have been hidden.

Related links:

- [FAQ about spam and offensive flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035)
- [Remove links when a post is deleted by Community from spam/offensive flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131026)
- [Offensive answers don't seem to get censored when manually deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308419/1743880): this post is about answer manually deleted; in this case it was *automatically* deleted by the Community user.

Comment: I'm not sure but this *might be* by design. Given the number of 10k+ users then subset the number of those that look at that link it'd just be annoying when using that view for its purpose of reviewing stuff to have to go to posts to see uncensored stuff. The censoring is mostly to just avoid accidentally walking into NSFW/etc... content when browsing the main site. When using the 10k+ review tools, it's probably expected that you realise "bad stuff" could turn up and are prepared for it to do so.

Comment: @HansPassant Not sure this is a duplicate of that one- Tunaki specifically says that on the actual post, the content is censored and this is only occuring with the 10k+ tools. That post is talking about the content in the actual post not being censored.

Comment: I also suspect that this is intentional and would not want to see it changed. It's useful to always see the original content in this review tool.